# Is every p-adic extension a finite-tailed laurent series?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, laurent-series

At the bottom of page 2 of this:

http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~lagarias/575chomework/p-adic-chap5.pdf

Lagarias states that the p-adic expansion of any rational number $x$ is a finite-tailed Laurent series in powers of $p$.

But I appear to be misunderstanding something since I make the expansions of fractions infinite. Take $\frac{2}{3}$ for example:

$$-1=\overline 1_2$$
$$\frac{-1}{3}=\overline{01}_2$$
$$\frac{2}{3}=1-\frac{1}{3}=\overline{01}10_2$$

Which would make its expansion $2^1+2^2+2^4+2^6+2^8...$

But that is not what I would call a finite-tailed expansion, since it is clearly infinite! Am I missing something? Or by finite-tailed, does he simply mean it has no negative powers of $p$?

Comment: I think he means that there are only finitely many negative powers of $p$

Comment: He means that in any $p-$adic expansion of a rational number, There is a finite number of digits which appear infinitely. in your example for $-1$, the digit $1$ (finite) appears infinitely.

Comment: We say that the Laurent-series field $\kappa((t))$ consists of finite-tailed series, and mean by this that every element there is of form $t^{-m}f(t)$ for some $m\ge0$ and some $f\in\kappa[[t]]$. It’s the same for $p$-adic numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By finite tailed, he means that the index of the sum formally defining the $p$-adic expansion has  a lower limit:

$$
\frac{a}{b} = \sum_{k\geq n_0} a_kp^k
$$

For the rationals, your speculation about finite-tailed meaning no negative powers is "right," in the sense that no negative powers does imply finite tailed.  But you could also start from, say, $p^{-4}$ and still be finite-tailed.

Comment: Thanks. Only you can fix the typo since it will require less than 6 chars!  Is this definitely right as opposed to what Omar Khayyam said, which is also true of p-adics, namely that there is only a finite number of digits appearing infinitely, or in other words the digits to the left always recur.

Comment: Since a conventional p-adic number is infinite to the left (positive powers) and a finite-tailed laurent series is finite to the right (negative powers) does that mean with an INFINITE-tailed Laurent series we can have a series which is infinite in both directions?